# How to get conegstion window in using socket identifier

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp

I have the TCP connection set up between client and server. I have the socket identifier of the connection and I would like to know how to get the tcp congestion window using this. I tried using `tcp.info` struture. But I observed it never changes throughout the session. Is there a way other than this , I can get the congestion window?

Does the socket buffer  size also specifies the window size? I guess its not.

Any system call that can do the above?

Comment: Which OS are you talking about ?

Comment: And in what way did you use the `tcp_info` structure

Comment: as shown [here](http://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html)

Comment: And the congestion window value was wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't change ... means it remains constant  in the whole duration of the session ..  but tcp.info.recv_thrsh changes .. does that mean this is the congestion window .